# QT Jambi installation failure/error on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: java, macos, qt, qt-jambi

I'm trying to install QT Jambi on my Mac because I've fallen in love with it.

But when I'm trying to install it via sh I get this message:

```
mm-air:qtjambi mm$ sh qtjambi.sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.trolltech.qt.QtJambiObject.<clinit>(QtJambiObject.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Loading library failed, progress so far:
Unpacking .jar file: 'qtjambi-macosx-gcc-4.7.0.jar'
Checking Archive 'qtjambi-macosx-gcc-4.7.0.jar'
 - cache key='gcc-20101012-2105'
 - adding 'libQtCore.4.dylib' to library map
 - library: name='lib/libQtCore.4.dylib', 
 - adding 'libQtGui.4.dylib' to library map
 - library: name='lib/libQtGui.4.dylib', 
 - adding 'libQtXml.4.dylib' to library map
 - library: name='lib/libQtXml.4.dylib', 
 - adding 'libQtSql.4.dylib' to library map
 - library: name='lib/libQtSql.4.dylib', 
 - adding 'libQtSvg.4.dylib' to library map
 - library: name='lib/libQtSvg.4.dylib', 
 - adding 'libQtNetwork.4.dylib' to library map
 - library: name='lib/libQtNetwork.4.dylib', 
 - adding 'libQtHelp.4.dylib' to library map
 - library: name='lib/libQtHelp.4.dylib', 
 - adding 'libQtScript.4.dylib' to library map
 - library: name='lib/libQtScript.4.dylib', 
 - adding 'libQtScriptTools.4.dylib' to library map
 - library: name='lib/libQtScriptTools.4.dylib', 
...
 - library: name='lib/libphonon.4.dylib', 
 - library: name='plugins/phonon_backend/libphonon_qt7.dylib', never load
 - library: name='plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.dylib', never load
 - library: name='plugins/imageformats/libqgif.dylib', never load
 - library: name='plugins/imageformats/libqmng.dylib', never load
 - library: name='plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.dylib', never load
 - library: name='plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.dylib', never load
 - library: name='plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.dylib', never load
 - library: name='plugins/codecs/libqcncodecs.dylib', never load
 - library: name='plugins/codecs/libqjpcodecs.dylib', never load
 - library: name='plugins/codecs/libqkrcodecs.dylib', never load
 - library: name='plugins/codecs/libqtwcodecs.dylib', never load
 - library: name='plugins/accessible/libqtaccessiblewidgets.dylib', never load
 - adding 'libqtjambi.jnilib' to library map
 - library: name='lib/libqtjambi.jnilib', 
 - adding 'libcom_trolltech_qt_core.jnilib' to library map
...
 - library: name='lib/libcom_trolltech_qt_xmlpatterns.jnilib', 
 - plugin path='plugins'
 - using cache directory:     '/var/folders/16/fyg5mv952wj9j8l5_z89svbh0000gn/T/QtJambi_mm_x86_64_4.7.0_gcc-20101012-2105'
 - cache directory exists
Loading library: 'libQtCore.4.dylib'...
 - using deployment spec

    at     com.trolltech.qt.internal.NativeLibraryManager.loadNativeLibrary(NativeLibraryManager.java:431)
at com.trolltech.qt.internal.NativeLibraryManager.loadQtLibrary(NativeLibraryManager.java:356)
at com.trolltech.qt.Utilities.loadQtLibrary(Utilities.java:145)
at com.trolltech.qt.Utilities.loadQtLibrary(Utilities.java:141)
at com.trolltech.qt.QtJambi_LibraryInitializer.<clinit>(QtJambi_LibraryInitializer.java:56)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:     /private/var/folders/16/fyg5mv952wj9j8l5_z89svbh0000gn/T/QtJambi_mm_x86_64_4.7.0_gcc-20101012-2105/lib/libQtCore.4.dylib:     dlopen(/private/var/folders/16/fyg5mv952wj9j8l5_z89svbh0000gn/T/QtJambi_mm_x86_64_4.7.0_gcc    -20101012-2105/lib/libQtCore.4.dylib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/folders/16/fyg5mv952wj9j8l5_z89svbh0000gn/T/QtJambi_mm_x86_64_4.7.0_gcc-20101012-2105/lib/libQtCore.4.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1929)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1814)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:797)
at com.trolltech.qt.internal.NativeLibraryManager.loadLibrary_helper(NativeLibraryManager.java:458)
at  com.trolltech.qt.internal.NativeLibraryManager.loadNativeLibrary(NativeLibraryManager.java:426)
... 5 more
```

I am grateful for every single attempt/hints to help me solve this.

Comment: The error is here: ”libQtCore.4.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture”. So the Mac package does not support your java’s architecture.

Comment: The OSX packages we have are just randomly built by some third party, we’d really need someone to give some love to them. Want to volunteer? :P That about best advice I can give... :)

Comment: Yes, I'd like to volunteer. May I contact you personally because I have got a few questions.

Comment: Yes, of course :) One contact method is email, one is through our IRC channel. Email is my nick and and domain smar.fi.